# cannot make custom changes to plesk httpd.conf

Tags: apache-2.2

I need to add some configuration parameters in the plesk server httpd.conf. but everytime i make canges, and make some changes in plesk , then those changes in httpd.conf are lost. is there any way i can add cutom configuration parameters in httpd.conf?

Regards,

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put you content in conf/vhost.conf or conf/vhost_ssl.conf. The usage is described in ["How to include domain-specific Apache configuration directives into web server configuration file"](http://kb.parallels.com/en/5464)